# Connect two external monitors on MacBook Pro M1, 2020

Tags: macbook-pro, display, apple-silicon

I want to connect to two external monitors on my company provided MacBook Pro M1, 2020. I am aware that by default we cannot connect to more than one external monitors on M1 chip, and there are workarounds like installing DisplayLink. However, DisplayLink requires admin privileges during the installation which I do not have in my company provided MacBook. Therefore, I am not able to install DisplayLink or any other software.

Can someone suggest me an alternative way to connect to two external monitors.

Comment: Anything that requires a driver, like a USB Video Adapter will require admin privileges to install. Why not ask your company’s IT for help?

Answer (score 0):

DisplayLink didn't work for me. But [InstantView](https://plugable.com/pages/siliconmotion) did.